# Undefined index in associative array and error in MySQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to INSERT data into a database table, I've been getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: follower_user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\newentry.php on line 29
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'post', 12, NOW(), NOW())' at line 1

The related code is as follows:

```
$node_sql = "SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE followed_blog_id=".$row['id']." order by id DESC;";
    $node_result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($node_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($node_result)){

            $event_sql = "INSERT INTO events (followed_id, follower_id, type, item_id, last_active, date) VALUES (".$row['id'].", ".$node_row['follower_user_id'].", 'post', ".$item_id.", NOW(), NOW());";
            mysql_query($event_sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

While the notice says the index "follower_user_id" is undefined on line 29, I checked the database table and it is the correct index spelled correctly, so I have no idea as to what is causing this problem.
I've also checked the syntax for the SQL statement and I don't see any problem with it. What have I overlooked here?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you see if you `echo $event_sql;`?

Comment: You have 2 sql statement which one are you using? `$node_sql` or `$sql`

Comment: I think you are using the wrong query.

Comment: Yeah, wrong query, can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 2
$node_result = mysql_query($sql);
should probably use $node_sql as the variable in the query call.
I think the generated INSERT statement has a blank $node_row['follower_user_id'] so there are two commas with nothing in between, causing the sql parser to cry :)

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! I can't believe I overlooked such a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the comment link on the question, so I'll post it as an answer.

You're using a single quote on 'post' whereas every other value is covered in double quotes.

Hint: You can freely use variables alone when within a double-quoted statement. Easy SQL on the eyes.

Here's the updated version of the SQL INSERT line:

```
$event_sql = "INSERT INTO events (followed_id, follower_id, type, item_id, last_active, date)
              VALUES ({$row["id"]}, {$node_row["follower_user_id"]},
                      `post`, $item_id, NOW(), NOW();";
```

Comment: The reason why I used single quotes is because "post" is not a variable, but rather a value I want to insert into the column manually.